# create chat server

Tags: c#, instant-messaging

we are thinking to add chat and messages to our product. (like MSN)
how can we create that , and how can a server call a client ? not the client calls the sever every couple of seconds?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the server to seem to *push*, you may want to look at [long-polling technologies such as "Comet"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29). But in my recent experience with [chat.stackoverflow.com](http://chat.stackoverflow.com) / [chat.stackexchange.com](http://chat.stackexchange.com) - client polling can work reasonably well too, as long as you keep things sane.

Comment: @Guy well, I don't want to give away *all* our tricks, but (for example) we do things like throttling down the rate based on activity. If it is quiet, no need to poll aggressively.

Comment: nice idea we use it also, because we are working with transactions + time is very important + we have a lot of users we want to push the message to our clients not for then to request data every couple of seconds -> so your suggest comet ? by the way its a winform product can we do it under poet 80 ?

Comment: @Guy - for winforms, you might also want to look at some of the 2-way WCF offerings

Comment: did you mean full duplex? by the way what do you think of pulling vs pushing?